# How to populate a combobox using an arraylist?

Tags: excel, vba, arraylist

I am trying to populate a combo box using an arraylist. I used the following code but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        Sheets("MSS").Select
            
Dim counter As Integer
Dim cmbox_opt As String
Dim array_cmbox As ArrayList
Set array_cmbox = New ArrayList
Dim last_row As Integer
Dim i As Integer
    
    
last_row = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
For counter = 3 To last_row
    cmbox_opt = Range("B" & counter).Value
    If Not array_cmbox.Contains(cmbox_opt) Then
          array_cmbox.Add cmbox_opt
    End If
Next
For i = 1 To i = 1 + i
    If array_cmbox.Contains(array_cmbox(i)) Then
        Me.ComboBoxArea.AddItem array_cmbox(i)
    End If
Next
    
    
    
        'Ensure Window Dimensions'
        With Me
            .Width = 577
            .Caption = "Master Sanitation Schedule Form v.1.0"
            .Height = 274
        End With

End Sub
```

However, if I just add the line

```
Me.ComboBoxArea.AddItem array_cmbox(2)
```

It does add the second item to the combo box from the ArrayList

Comment: `ArrrayList` is not VBA type ... do you have a class? Furthermore: `For i = 1 To i = 1 + i` doesn't make sense, because `i = 1 + i` will always resolve to `false`= 0. What you presumably need is `For i = 1 to ubound(array_cmbox)`

Answer (score 1):

### Populate a Combo Box Using an Array List

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        
    PopulateComboBoxArea
    
    'Ensure Window Dimensions'
    With Me
        .Width = 577
        .Caption = "Master Sanitation Schedule Form v.1.0"
        .Height = 274
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub PopulateComboBoxArea()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const wsName As String = "MSS"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 3
    Const Col As String = "B"
        
    ' Reference the workbook ('wb').
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the worksheet ('ws').
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    
    ' Calculate the last row ('LastRow'),
    ' the row of the last non-empty cell in the column.
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Validate the last row.
    If FirstRow > LastRow Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Reference the one-column range ('crg').
    Dim crg As Range
    Set crg = ws.Range(ws.Cells(FirstRow, Col), ws.Cells(LastRow, Col))
        
    ' Write the number of rows to a variable ('rCount').
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = crg.Rows.Count
        
    ' Write the values from the (one-column) range
    ' to a 2D one-based (one-column) array ('cData').
    Dim cData() As Variant
    If rCount = 1 Then ' one cell
        ReDim cData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): cData(1, 1) = crg.Value
    Else ' multiple cells
        cData = crg.Value
    End If
    
    ' Create and reference a new array list.
    ' Either early binding: needs a reference to 'mscorlib.dll'...
    'Dim arl As ArrayList: Set arl = New ArrayList
    ' ... or late binding: no reference needed
    Dim arl As Object: Set arl = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    ' IMO, this would be the way to go since when using early binding,
    ' the Intellisense, that would be useful to easily learn how to use
    ' the array list, doesn't work at this moment.
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim r As Long ' Current Array Row
    Dim cString As String ' Current Array Value Converted to a String
    
    ' Loop through the rows of the array...
    For r = 1 To rCount
        ' Write the value converted to a string to a variable ('cString').
        cString = CStr(cData(r, 1))
        ' Check if the string doesn't exist in the array list.
        If Not arl.Contains(cString) Then ' string is not in the array list...
            arl.Add cString ' ... so add it
        'Else ' string is already in the array list; do nothing
        End If
    Next r
    
    ' IMO, a huge disadvantage, compared to the dictionary, is that
    ' you cannot compare the strings case-insensitively when using 'Contains'.
    ' When using a dictionary you could simply use
    ' e.g. dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare' making e.g. 'A = a'.
    
    ' IMO, one of the very few reasons to use an array list over a dictionary
    ' is that you can easily sort it:
    arl.Sort
    
    ' Populate the combo box with the values from the array list
    ' (no need to loop).
    Me.ComboBoxArea.List = arl.ToArray

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much I still have a ton of learning to do with VBA and this was very helpful. So would you say in the future for similar projects I should avoid using the arraylist?

Comment: Not necessarily but in 'my book' the order of preference should be array, collection, dictionary, and array list. You can use any data structure but you need to know what it can do and what it can't and act accordingly. In this particular case, to solve the case-sensitivity issue, you could manipulate the source data by 'uniforming' its case i.e. you could write the column data to the 2D array in the following ways: `cData = Application.Proper(crg)` or `cData = ws.Evaluate("UPPER(" & crg.Address & ")")` or `cData = ws.Evaluate("LOWER(" & crg.Address & ")")`.

Comment: Once again thanks for all the info it's of huge help. I was wondering if you guide me through the part where you write the values of the column range into the 2D one-based array.  When you change the dimensions of cData() how does the     If rCount = 1 Then ' one cell
        ReDim cData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): cData(1, 1) = crg.Value
    Else ' multiple cells
        cData = crg.Value
    End If part work?

Comment: You can write the values from a range to an array with `cData = rg.Value`, where `rg.Value` is already a `2D array` **only if there is more than one cell in the range** (you are actually assigning the array `rg.Value` to a variant array variable). If the range has only one cell then `rg.Value` is not an array but a single value that you can't assign to an array variable but you can resize the array to be of size `1 To 1, 1 To 1` and write the single value to the resized **one-element** array with `cData(1, 1) = rg.Value`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I think using [BinarySearch(Object, IComparer)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.binarysearch?view=netframework-4.8.1#system-collections-arraylist-binarysearch(system-object-system-collections-icomparer)) should be able to compare the strings case-insensitively. It's probably named ArrayList.BinarySearch_2 . Would required first sorting the ArrayList, so can reliable perform the BinarySearch, and a class implementing the mscorlib.IComparer.